# Clone element and increment index placed in name by 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

Lets say I have this input:

`name="fecha_inicio[2]"`

And I want to clone it and generate:

`name="fecha_inicio[3]"`

How can I do so?

I tried something like this, but Its ugly and it won't work..

```
var $input = $original.clone();
var name = $input.attr('name');     
name.replace('['+(indice-1)+']', '['+indice+']');   
$input.attr('name', name);
```

Comment: You can add a `data-id` attribute to the input, get that, and add the name attribute based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method doesn't modify string in place, but returns a new string. So your code should be:

```
name = name.replace('['+(indice-1)+']', '['+indice+']');
```

Also maybe you don't really need to have such index names. You can simply go with `name="fecha_inicio[]"` and don't worry about index. Later you would get form data with say serialize method.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! It doesn't seem to work.. any thoughts? http://jsfiddle.net/ufctj1f9/4/

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/ufctj1f9/5/. You just named the last row inputs the same as previous.